# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method lluminate\Foundation\Application::withEloquent()

Tags: php, cassandra, eloquent, laravel-5

I have install composer.json:

```
"require": {
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
"datastax/php-driver": "^1.2",
"sonvq/cassandra": "dev-master"
},
```

However, adding **bootstrap/app.php**:

> $app->register(sonvq\Cassandra\CassandraServiceProvider::class);
>   $app->withEloquent();

And adding to **config/app.php** in **'providers' => [ ]**:

```
sonvq\Cassandra\CassandraServiceProvider::class,
```

I still got this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application::withEloquent()

Answer (score 0):

The **withEloquent()** method is part of **Lumen** framework and is not available in **Laravel**. It's used to enable **Eloquent ORM** in **Lumen**. See the docs for more details: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Answer (score 0):

I also used "sonvq" package for cassandra. I think it is not a completed package. So tried with another package. https://github.com/cubettech/lacassa. It works.